# Get current PHP install settings

Tags: php, installation

I wanted to get the settings of the current installed PHP on my server. I don't want to have the settings of PHP(.ini) itself, I need the `/configure` parameters how the PHP is currently installed. E.g. the values of `--prefix` or `--includedir` or `--sysconfdir` of my currently PHP ...

Edit:
I know that `phpinfo()` will output the settings but on my server isn't a `Configure Command` field with the information! How do I get these information?

Edit #2:
Does nobody understand what I want to know or is my answer really that bad that I get so much downvotes?
A common use to install PHP is like that:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/share/php5\
 --with-libdir=lib64\
 --includedir=/usr/include\
 --enable-libxml\
 --enable-session
[...]
```

I didn't installed the current PHP5.2 on the server so I don't know how it was configurated during installation and I need/want to know what were the settings to install PHP5.3 like the current 5.2 to have a high chance to get all my websites working without any trouble.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How was my running php compiled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534116/how-was-my-running-php-compiled)

Comment: You are looking for the "php-config" Command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've said that your output from `phpinfo()` / `php -i` doesn't have a *Configure Command* section. Can you post the output of `php -i | head -n 10` ?

**EDIT**:

Based on your comment that states `PHP Version => 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.23`, it seems you're running Ubuntu. I found the list of which versions of Ubuntu include which version of PHP [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5), which implies you're running Hardy Heron. I found details of the particular source package [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.23), and the upload date corresponds to the build date that you see in your output of `php -i`. Since you're running a 64-bit version of the package, the complete Ubuntu buildlog can be found [here](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/92790964/buildlog_ubuntu-hardy-amd64.php5_5.2.4-2ubuntu5.23_BUILDING.txt.gz) (warning: LONG). Scrolling through that you can find the `configure` commands for the apache2 build on line 1815, the cgi build on line 6170 and the cli build on line 9164. To save you some scrolling, here's the command for the apache2 build (i.e. the package `libapache2-mod-php5`):

```
    CFLAGS="-O2 -Wall -fsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing   -gstabs" PROG_SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail" ../configure \
    --prefix=/usr --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2 \
    --with-config-file-path=/etc/php5/apache2 \
    --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d \
    --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-memory-limit --disable-debug --with-regex=php --disable-rpath --disable-static --with-pic --with-layout=GNU --with-pear=/usr/share/php --enable-calendar --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-sysvmsg --enable-track-vars --enable-trans-sid --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --enable-ctype --with-db4 --without-gdbm --with-iconv --enable-exif --enable-filepro --enable-ftp --with-gettext --enable-mbstring --with-pcre-regex=/usr --enable-shmop --enable-sockets --enable-wddx --with-libxml-dir=/usr --with-zlib --with-kerberos=/usr --with-openssl=/usr --enable-dbx --enable-soap --enable-zip --with-mime-magic=/usr/share/file/magic.mime --with-exec-dir=/usr/lib/php5/libexec --with-system-tzdata \
    --without-mm \
    --with-curl=shared,/usr \
    --with-zlib-dir=/usr \
    --with-gd=shared,/usr --enable-gd-native-ttf \
    --with-gmp=shared,/usr \
    --with-jpeg-dir=shared,/usr \
    --with-xpm-dir=shared,/usr/X11R6 \
    --with-png-dir=shared,/usr \
    --with-freetype-dir=shared,/usr \
    --with-ttf=shared,/usr \
    --with-t1lib=shared,/usr \
    --with-ldap=shared,/usr \
    --with-ldap-sasl=/usr \
    --with-mhash=shared,/usr \
    --with-mysql=shared,/usr \
    --with-mysqli=shared,/usr/bin/mysql_config \
    --with-pspell=shared,/usr \
    --with-unixODBC=shared,/usr \
    --with-recode=shared,/usr \
    --with-xsl=shared,/usr \
    --with-snmp=shared,/usr \
    --with-sqlite=shared,/usr \
    --with-mssql=shared,/usr \
    --with-tidy=shared,/usr \
    --with-xmlrpc=shared \
    --with-pgsql=shared,/usr PGSQL_INCLUDE=`pg_config --includedir` \
    --enable-pdo=shared \
    --without-pdo-dblib \
    --with-pdo-mysql=shared,/usr \
    --with-pdo-odbc=shared,unixODBC,/usr \
    --with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr/bin/pg_config \
    --with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/usr \
    --with-pdo-dblib=shared,/usr
```

Comment: The output:
    `phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.23

System => Linux - dedicated 2.6.18-028stab092.1 #1 SMP Wed Jul 20 11:44:12 MSD 2011 x86_64
Build Date => Feb 11 2012 05:49:55
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d`

Comment: I've updated my answer with references to the Ubuntu buildlog.

Comment: @MarioHaubenwallner your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 11):

You are looking for the [`php-config`](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php-config.php) command. Running this will spit out everything PHP knows about it's installation and creation. Specifically, the following flags will tell you about the compilation of the php binary.

> ```
> --prefix  Directory prefix where PHP is installed, e.g. /usr/local
>
> --ldflags LD Flags which PHP was compiled with
>
> --libs    Extra libraries which PHP was compiled with
>
> --configure-options   Configure options to recreate configuration of current 
>           PHP installation
> ```

The command only accepts one flag at a time, so it may be better to run it without flags.

Example output:

```
$ php-config
Usage: /usr/bin/php-config [OPTION]
Options:
  --prefix            [/usr]
  --includes          [-I/usr/include/php ...snip ]
  --ldflags           []
  --libs              [-lcrypt   -lresolv -lcrypt ...snip ]
  --extension-dir     [/usr/lib64/php/modules]
  --include-dir       [/usr/include/php]
  --man-dir           [/usr/share/man]
  --php-binary        [/usr/bin/php]
  --php-sapis         [cli cgi]
  --configure-options [--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --host= ...snip]
  --version           [5.3.29]
  --vernum            [50329]
```

Where the bit after each `Option` in the list isn't just an example output, it's the actual value; it is what you get if you call `php-config` with that option. E.g.

```
$ php-config --prefix
/usr
```

Comment: This was a great find and very helpful to me. I hope you don't mind that I added some details to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)

> phpinfo — Outputs information about PHP's configuration

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

---

You could run `php -i` from the command-line and see if you get different results.
Even though

> `php -i` calls phpinfo(), and prints out the results,

the results may differ from `<?php phpinfo() ?>` since the command-line may have it's own php.ini.

Comment: @Poru what are the specific settings you can't seem to get a hold of?

Comment: The configure settings for the installation of PHP.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

The [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) function will give you all the settings you're looking for, formatted as HTML.

Comment: +1 You gave the same answer, but you gave the right amount of info. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get the settings:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```