# How was my running php compiled?

Tags: compilation, configure, php

I'm trying to compile a new instance of PHP (5.4.0) from the source code and want to keep compatibility with the one (PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6) already installed from the distro, Ubuntu-11.10. That is, I want to run `./configure` with the same directives as the installed PHP.

I always could see the `./configure` command outputted by `phpinfo()` but this time, for my surprise, it's not provided.

Do you know of any flag that prevent `phpinfo` of outputting the compile configuration? Or,

Do you know of any other way to get how PHP was compiled?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### Original answer

There should be a script [php-config](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/php-config5.1.html) you can install on ubuntu to get the configure parameters used for php.

```bash
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
php-config  --configure-options
```

### 2023 Update

The `php-config` executable is currently present in the generic package `phpX.Y-dev`, where `X` and `Y` is the major and minor version of the php package installed on your system. Also, the name of the executable reflects your php version.

```bash
sudo apt-get install php8.1-dev
php-config8.1 --configure-options
```

A list of popular ubuntu version and corresponding package:

- Ubuntu 18.04: [php7.2-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/php7.2-dev)
- Ubuntu 20.04: [php7.4-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/php7.4-dev)
- Ubuntu 21.04: [php7.4-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/php7.4-dev)
- Ubuntu 21.10: [php8.0-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/php8.0-dev)
- Ubuntu 22.04: [php8.1-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/php8.1-dev)
- Ubuntu 22.10: [php8.1-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/php8.1-dev)
- Ubuntu 23.04*¹: [php8.1-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/php8.1-dev)

**¹ Lunar Lobster nightly, scheduled to be released as 23.04*

Comment: On Ubunutu 12.04 `php-config` is included in the `php5-dev` package

Comment: This will update some of the modules or install new ones on my server
New `libapache2-mod-php5 libltdl-dev libtool php5-cgi php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-intl php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-pgsql php5-sqlite  shtool` Update `libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cgi php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-gd
  php5-intl php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-pgsql php5-sqlite`

Answer (score 10):

According to [this bug report](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-server-bugs/2010-April/034631.html), the `Configure Command` output was intentionally suppressed from Ubuntu & Debian PHP builds.

Then recommend installing the source package via `apt-get source php5`:

> If you want to see how PHP is built in Ubuntu, `apt-get source php5`,
>   and peruse debian/rules, the ./configure output in phpinfo() is, as the
>   changelog for the patch states, entirely misleading and not terribly
>   informative.

Comment: I like this answer too, but Aron's hits the nail on the head