# Understanding include_path output PHP

Tags: php

I need help in understanding include_path and where it is set. When I echo include path this is what I see:

```
.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php
```

From what I understand there are two paths currently in the include_path separated by colon. First one is the

```
'.' which indicates the current directory
```

and the second one is the path

```
'/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php'
```

So my questions are:

```
1) Is the above understanding correct?
2) Where is the include_path set because I looked at my php.ini file  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc but I couldn't find this being mentioned in the file
```

This is what my php.ini had and the same seems to be commented:

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
```

Also including my phpinfo output

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc
Loaded Configuration File   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path . the default is `.;/path/to/php/pear` this can be changed from all places including code. so you may need to check the XAMPP's php configuration, any htaccess file etc....

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. In `php.ini` like you thought. Use `phpinfo();` to see what configuration files gets loaded. There could be additional `php.ini` files or this is not correct `php.ini` file loaded. Also, it can be easily changed from PHP code, `.htaccess` files etc.

In `phpinfo()` output, search for `Loaded Configuration File` and `Additional .ini files parsed`.

From command line, use command `php -i` to get php info.

Comment: this is the output of phpinfo. As you see Loaded Configuration file is the one I mentioned and Additional .ini files parsed are none: Using ::::: for better readability                                                                                           Configuration File (php.ini) Path  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc
::::: Loaded Configuration File  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
::::::Scan this dir for additional .ini files  (none)
::::::Additional .ini files parsed  (none)

Comment: Then it gets changed somewhere else. This could be changed with [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) etc.

Answer (score 0):

## 1) Is your understanding of the `include_path` correct?

Yes. The `include_path` is a list of directories separated with a colon in Unix or semicolon in Windows. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

## 2) Where is the `include_path` set?

> Where is the `include_path` set because I looked at my `php.ini` file in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc` but I couldn't find this being mentioned in the file. 
>   This is what my php.ini had and the same seems to be commented:
>
> ```
> ; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
> ;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
> ```

In a nutshell, your version of PHP was compiled with a default `include_path` of `.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php`. If there is no value for an ini setting PHP will fallback to its default.

Note: In ini files, lines beginning with `;` are comments.

- [How is my running PHP compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534116/how-was-my-running-php-compiled)
- [How to find the php.ini file used by the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750580/how-to-find-the-php-ini-file-used-by-the-command-line)
- [Dude, where's my php.ini?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/dude-wheres-my-php-ini)