# Where exactly do I place the PHPmailer folder if I am using XAMPP?

Tags: php, xampp, phpmailer

Good day, I want to use PHPmailer to send emails to users so they can reset their password. I am running localhost using XAMPP but I don't know where to place the PHPMailer folder so it can work. Do I place it in the main directory of the XAMPP folder or do I place it in the htdocs subfolder?

Comment: It doesn't really matter as PHP can read the library even if it is sitting above your web root. The docs say, _"... then copy the contents of the PHPMailer folder into one of the include_path directories specified in your PHP configuration and load each class file manually"_ and you can read about include_path here https://stackoverflow.com/q/34545291/296555. But I strongly suggest you install Composer if you don't have it installed already and start using it. It is the de facto library manager for PHP and it quite easy to use once you get the auto-load setup.

Comment: But to answer your question directly, I'd just store it in along with your other libraries, wherever they are installed.